# How to change XPath queries to predicate map for the QueryBuilder in CQ5?

Tags: xpath, aem

I am trying to convert XPath queries to predicates that I can use with the QueryBuilder. 
For example, I have an XPath as follows:

```
xpath = "/jcr:root/content/dam//metadata[picturepark:id >= " 
            + startId + " and picturepark:id <= " + endId + "]";
```

I want to use QueryBuilder instead of XPath. For that I need a ValueMap. 
Can anyone tell me what the equivalent ValueMap would be for this XPath?

Also, please suggest some reference material that would help me in general to change other XPath queries to a QueryBuilder format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the Querybuilder equivalent of the given Xpath query. You can check whether it results the same as that of your Xpath through the Querydebugger(/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html) console of CQ instance.

```
type=dam:Asset
path=/content/dam
rangeproperty.property=jcr:content/metadata/picturepark:id
rangeproperty.lowerBound=startId
rangeproperty.lowerOperation=>=
rangeproperty.upperBound=endid
rangeproperty.upperOperation=<=
```

For reference you can refer to the [Query Builder API docs](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) and the [Predicate Evaluator Java Docs](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PredicateEvaluator.html) for all the supported predicates.